# application to manage multiple outlook accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

I have multiple outlook accounts, and all accounts are added to the outlook express.
I can list emails from inbox in asp.net application from one account only which is set as default.
I can list emails from another account by setting it as default data file..

here is my code :

```
public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items GetHotMailInBoxItemsUsingLoggedInOutLookAccount(this string strMailStatus)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace _ns;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items _items = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application _application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        _ns = _application.Session;
        inboxFolder = _ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        if (strMailStatus.Equals("1"))
        {
            _items = inboxFolder.Items;
        }
        else
        {
            _items = strMailStatus.Equals("2") ? inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true") : inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = false");
        }
        _items.Sort("ReceivedTime", true);
        return _items;
    }
```

I want to switch "_application.Session" as i want.
ie: change the default data file from asp.net application..

Comment: This should prove helpful to you despite it's age: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/91530/outlook-profile-switching

Comment: "Switch" in what sense? What kind of account are these?

Comment: I have two outlook accounts. I want to list emails from inboxes of these two accounts as user requests.....

Answer (score 0):

Consider using EWS (Exchange Web Services) instead. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article.